# How do I get http post to send data to backend. front end is angular 2 and backend is .net 5

Tags: asp.net, angular, http-post

Here is the error I am getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "http://localhost:49873/api/home". Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '//localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 400.

Here is my controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3000", headers: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", methods: "GET, POST")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] book inbook)
    {
        book fromangular = inbook;
        var body = this.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<book>();
        return Ok(fromangular);
    }
}
```

And here is my angular 2 code:

```
postBook(inBook: book)
{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let x = JSON.stringify(inBook);
    var res = this._http.post(booksUlr, x, { headers }).map((response:                      
                            Response ) => response.json()).subscribe();
    return;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled CORS on your WebApi's HttpConfiguration? I believe you need to explicitly enable it for the Controller Attributes to work.

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.EnableCors();
```

Or you could enable it globally.

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000", "*", "*"));
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Based on the [documentation](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), try enabling all the methods when declaring the attribute and then disabling the specific actions you don't want to grant access to.

For example

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3000", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] book inbook)
    {
        book fromangular = inbook;
        var body = this.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<book>();
        return Ok(fromangular);
    }
    [DisableCors]
    // some action
}
```

Also, unsure if this will help but in the documentation the 'methods:"get, post"' are in lowercase, but that doesn't explain why the get method works fine.

Comment: Yes I did allow that. the strange thing is that GET methods work but POST  refuse to work.